# RColorBrewer colors differ between plot types

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working with ggplot2 + RColorBrewer to create a set of graphs. I would like to get my colors matching across graphs, but this is proving surprisingly difficult.

Here's a simplified example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)

set.seed(1)

df <- tibble(x=rnorm(600),
               y = as.factor(rep(1:6, 100)))

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=y)) +
  stat_boxplot(alpha=.7, outlier.shape=5) +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set3")
  ggsave(file="fig1.pdf", width = 210/2, height = 297/2, units = "mm")
dev.off()

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=y, color=y)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set3") +
  stat_summary(fun=median, geom='point', shape=17, size=3, alpha=.7) +
  theme_minimal() 
  ggsave(file="fig2.pdf", width = 210/2, height = 297/2, units = "mm")
```

The resulting fig1 looks as follows:
[image]

And fig2 is ends up looking like this:
[image]

The issue is that the colors do not exactly match. For example, group y=1 is green in Fig1 and red in Fig2. Clearly the two pictures are based on the same palette, but the order is different. Is there a way to force the same order in the two graphs (I am reluctant to hard-code colour codes in the graph)?

Comment: The point `shape=17` has only a `color` aesthetic. Hence you have to use `scale_color_brewer`. Or as a second option use `shape=24` which has both a color and a fill aes. Or as a third option use `scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set3", aesthetics = c("fill", "color"))` to apply the color palette to both the fill and the color aes.

Comment: Aha I see! Where can I find out which shapes have a color aesthetic?

Comment: See e.g. https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-specs.html#sec:shape-spec The red ones have both color for the outline and a fill.

Comment: Ok, now I get it! Thanks so much @stefan! Please free to post your first comment as an answer if you would like a boost in your rep. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `shape=17` has only a `color` aesthetic. Hence you have to use `scale_color_brewer` to get the same colors.

Note: For an overview of the `shape`s and which one has a `color` or both a `color` and `fill` aes see the [Aesthetic specifications](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-specs.html#sec:shape-spec) vignette.

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(
  x = rnorm(600),
  y = as.factor(rep(1:6, 100))
)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = y, color = y)) +
  theme_minimal()

p +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set3") +
  stat_summary(fun = median, geom = "point", shape = 17, size = 3, alpha = .7)
```

[image]

A second option would be to switch to `shape=24` which has both a `color` and a `fill` aes. Note that here I used `stroke=0` to remove the outline

```r
p +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set3") +
  stat_summary(fun = median, geom = "point", shape = 24, size = 3, alpha = .7, stroke = 0)
```

[image]

Or as a third option use `scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set3", aesthetics = c("fill", "color"))` to apply the color palette to both the `fill` and the `color` aes.

```r
p +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set3", aesthetics = c("fill", "color")) +
  stat_summary(fun = median, geom = "point", shape = 17, size = 3, alpha = .7)
```

[image]

Comment: I tend to use `ggpubr::show_point_shapes()` - probably the only function I'm using from this package :D

Comment: @tjebo Good to know. I've written myself a bunch of functions info_shape, info_linewidth, ... containing basically the info from the referenced ggplot2 vignette. :D